# how do I properly wrap a type in c++

Tags: c++

So, let me restart from scratch. 
This is my minimal reproducible example.

All the code here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "glm/glm.hpp"

class Vector3 : public glm::vec3
{
public:
        Vector3(): glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
        {

        };

        Vector3(float _x, float _y, float _z) : glm::vec3(_x, _y, _z) 
        {

        };
};

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
        Vector3 pos1 = Vector3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Vector3 pos2 = Vector3(10.0f, 1.0f, 0.6f);

        float dist = glm::distance(pos1,pos2);

        printf("distance : %.3f\n" , dist);

        return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get this error :

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:23:38: error: cannot convert ‘Vector3’ to ‘float’ in initialization
  float dist = glm::distance(pos1,pos2);
```

Why is it trying to convert to a float and not to a glm::vec3 ?

My goal is just to be able to use Vector3 class as if it was a glm::vec3, but for some methods I would add to it.

For now it compiles only if I explicitly cast to glm::vec3 :

```
float dist = glm::distance((glm::vec3)pos1,(glm::vec3)pos2);
```

My question is : How can I get rid of this explicit cast ?

I read a little about implicit conversion, it seems to be what I need, but I fail to make it work at the moment.

Comment: It looks like your initializer list for `Vector3::Vector3` uses 3 undefined variables `x,y,z` - what are you really trying to do here?

Comment: yes, this is silly ( I did that when trying to make it work ) I have exactly the same behavior when using glm::vec3() with no params though

Comment: You should use `glm::vec3(_x, _y, _z)` in the intializer list. `glm::vec3()` won't use the x,y,z parameters in your constructor unless you manually assign them in the constructor body (that is unnecessary). Also, you can implement [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) operators on your class to avoid having to write explicit casts.

Comment: @Romen a derived class should automatically implicitly convert to a base class.  I don't understand why casting was necessary in this case at all.

Comment: hm ok, so my probelm lies somewhere else. I edited my question with the error message I get when i don't explicitly cast. Thank you for the info on "implicit conversion", that's a pretty hairy page ;) , a lot to learn !

Comment: Use containment, not inheritance.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your error message is unrelated to any code you have shown.

Comment: I editied the error part, silly I missed it it , it was on top a long error, the error is much clearer now, but I still don't get it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I started the question from scratch. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Arff, my question was totally misguided.

I tried inheriting from a simple custom class instead of glm::vec3, and providing my own distance function, 
and it works as expected.

Looking at the code for glm::vec3 ( which I should have read before ...) glm uses a pretty complicated template system which I don't understand.

This doesn't answer the question above, but it clarifies a lot inheritance for me.

I still don't undertand why I can't inherit from glm::vec3 the same way though.
That's what I should have written as the question title.